# How to show user LoginId in app-drawer after successfully login with API

Tags: json, flutter, api

I successfully integrate my login API , also able to print it on another page by doing  `Text("Name: ${widget.response.userData!.name}"),`. But I want to display the user LoginId in app-drawer after login with correct credentials.

[image]

Here is my `login()` function, which is trigger when user press the login button

```
Future<void> login() async{
    var jsonResponse = null;
if (passwordontroller.text.isNotEmpty && emailController.text.isNotEmpty) {
  var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://mnmnmnmnmnmnmnmnmnn"),
      body: ({
        'LoginId': emailController.text,
        'Password': passwordontroller.text
      }));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("Correct");
    print(response.body);
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
    print(jsonResponse);
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>AfterLoginResPage(response: ApiResponse.fromJson(jsonResponse))));
  }
```

My API model:

```
    class ApiResponse {
    ApiResponse({
        required this.status,
        required this.message,
        required this.userData,
    });

    String status;
    String message;
   // UserData userData;
    UserData? userData; 

    factory ApiResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ApiResponse(
        status: json["Status"],
        message: json["Message"],
        //userData: UserData.fromJson(json["UserData"]),
         userData: json["UserData"] == null? null:UserData.fromJson(json["UserData"] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    );


}

class UserData {
    UserData({
        required this.name,
        required this.encUserId,
    });

    String name;
    String encUserId;

    factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserData(
        name: json["Name"],
        encUserId: json["EncUserId"],
    );

}
```

and after this i'm able to print my desired json data in my app by doing

`Text("Status: ${widget.response.status}"),`

`Text("Message: ${widget.response.message}"),`

`Text("Name: ${widget.response.userData!.name}"),`
`Text("encUserId: ${widget.response.userData!.encUserId}"),`

if I put this way in app app drawer screen the app getting crashed because user name is from `<Future>` How to achieve this so that I can display the Username? (for example `qwerty@gmail.com`)

Here is my json response in postman

```
 {
    "Status": "1",
    "Message": "You are Logged in successfully",
    "UserData": {
        "Name": "qwerty@gmail.com",
        "EncUserId": "GO9gj3aSUKCpxE3AMSbh/A=="
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use getStorage package https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage to store the name right after the Api call and use the storage variable anywhere in your app you can also use sharedPreference too.

```
main() async {
 //iniatialize the getStorage
 await GetStorage.init();
runApp(child: MyApp());
 }`
final box = GetStorage(); //instance of getStorage
```

.

```
 Future<void> login() async{
var jsonResponse = null;
if (passwordontroller.text.isNotEmpty && emailController.text.isNotEmpty) 
 {
 var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://mnmnmnmnmnmnmnmnmnn"),
  body: ({
    'LoginId': emailController.text,
    'Password': passwordontroller.text
    }));
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print("Correct");
  print(response.body);
  jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
print(jsonResponse);
 var result = ApiResponse.fromJson(jsonResponse)
 await box.write('name',result.userData!.name) //<---store the String 
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
(context)=>AfterLoginResPage(response: result)));
  }
```

.

```
//Use the Stored name anywhere
String name = box.read('name');
Text(name)
```